# selenium driver quit/close throw error in function - python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ipython, exit

I am running into errors every time when the driver close/quit inside a function. The environment is,
Max OS X El Capitan (version 10.11.6), 
IPython 4.2.0, 
Python 2.7.13, 
selenium 3.12.0 (it also happens on 3.4.1 before I updated it)

Specifically, when I run through each line of code in test0 or test1 (not run the functions) in Ipython, everything is ok. 
It is also ok when I run test0(). But IPython crashes when I run test1(), regardless of which of Chrome and Firefox I am using, nor use time.sleep to wait for any GUI to finish operating or not.

It doesn't happen on my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, though.

```
def test0():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()    # or Firefox()
    driver.get('http://www.google.com')

def test1():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()    # or Firefox()
    driver.get('http://www.google.com')
    time.sleep(5)   # use it or not
    driver.quit()
    time.sleep(5)   # use it or not

In [1]: test1()

Out[1]: /Users/xxx/anaconda/bin/python.app: line 3: 35509 Segmentation 
fault: 11  /Users/xxx/anaconda/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"
dhcp-xx-xxx-xx-xxx:~ $
```

Comment: In your example, where y close driver instance?

Comment: @Zhivko.Kostadinov there is a driver.quit(). It is the same effect when I replace it with driver.close()

Comment: Try to add on each test driver.quit() when y perform actions.